# Powershell Invoke questions

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am having trouble getting the syntax right for invokes. I can successfully do 
`powershell -Command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -force;. C:\WinUtils\Docs\machine_setup_functions.ps1;setup-oo-report}"` from a BAT file.
It loads the file and runs the function. I have a powershell script engine that allows entries in an XML file to be called. This is all driven from powershell. (Samples are given below).

I want to be able to call the function in a separate ps1 file and pass some arguments. Can someone advise what I am doing wrong as I am not sure of the nuances between invoke-expression and command.

Also, what is the best way to provide arguments to a function which may contain spaces or other special characters?

Thank you.

```
#
# Sample engine code 
#
#case 1
$function = "Function_Test"
$script = "C:\temp\test_called.ps1"
$optionargs = ""
<#case 2
$function = "Function_Test_Args"
$script = "C:\temp\test_called.ps1"
$optionargs = '"info for 1" "info for 2"' # not really sure the correct way to do this
#>
    $HasFunc = $function.Length -gt 0
    $theArgs = "{"
    if ($HasFunc)
    {
        $theArgs += ". " + $script + ";" + $function 
    }
    else
    {
        # no function so expect code in ps1 NOT in a function
        $theArgs += ". " + $script 
    }
    if ($optionalArgs.Length > 0)
    {
        $theArgs += " " + $optionalArgs
    }
    $theArgs += "}"
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $theArgs
    # No joy whether i use Invoke-expression, -command, none etc
```

Then a separate file

```
#
# sample called from other ps1
#
Function Function_Test
{
    Write-Output "Function_Test is running"
    Write-Host "Function_Test is running"
}

Function Function_Test_Args
{
param( 
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)] 
      [AllowEmptyString()] 
      [String]$Info1,
      [string]$Info2
    )

    Write-Output "Function_Test_Args #1 $Info1 #2 $Info2"
    Write-Host "Function_Test_Args #1 $Info1 #2 $Info2"
}
```

The sample above returns:

> [2015-10-30 11:50:26] Task taskg has aborted Cannot bind parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Cannot convert the "{. F:\ScriptWork\helloworld.ps1;Function_Test}" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".